# No such metthod error even after null check Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

I'm having some trouble with the edamam api when checking for values that might not exist. When querying the nutrional value of something like 'one pizza' there are no errors and the data is returned successfully but that's not the case for most queries eg.'one bowl of soup'.

I have a future builder that updates once the user sends their query in a textfield after pressing a button

```
if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.done &&
        snapshot.hasData &&
        !snapshot.hasError &&
        snapshot.data != null) {
      energy = snapshot.data['totalDaily']['ENERC_KCAL']['quantity'] == null
          ? 0.0
          : snapshot.data['totalDaily']['ENERC_KCAL']['quantity'];
      fat = snapshot.data['totalDaily']['FAT']['quantity'] == null
          ? 0.0
          : snapshot.data['totalDaily']['FAT']['quantity'];
      protein = snapshot.data['totalDaily']['PROCNT']['quantity'] == null
          ? 0.0
          : snapshot.data['totalDaily']['PROCNT']['quantity'];
      cholesterol = snapshot.data['totalDaily']['CHOLE']['quantity'] == null
          ? 0.0
          : snapshot.data['totalDaily']['CHOLE']['quantity'];
```

The variables get the info and depending on the if checks I return a loader or the info. I thought adding a null check will prevent any errors but they don't seem to do anything. This is the error I get

```
The following NoSuchMethodError was thrown building FutureBuilder<dynamic>(dirty, state: _FutureBuilderState<dynamic>#3bbe5):
    The method '[]' was called on null.
    Receiver: null
    Tried calling: []("quantity")
```

Is there a better way to do this? and what I'm I doing wrong here?

Comment: Can you provide your error log?

Comment: Your issue is that you're doing `x['quantity']` where `x` is `null`.  Your current null checks test that things such as `snapshot.data['totalDaily']['ENERC_KCAL']['quantity']` are not null, but that's too late; they neglect to check that `snapshot.data['totalDaily']['ENERC_KCAL']`, etc. are not null.  If you have null-safety features enabled, you can check `snapshot.data['totalDaily']?['ENERC_KCAL']?['quantity'] == null`.

Comment: So I tried it out like you said jamesdlin and the problem is fixed many thanks, but it is quite wordy. How do I enable the null-safety features so it is simplified like you wrote?

Comment: @NanaKwame Please check my answer for a less wordy solution

Comment: Enabling null-safety might be more work than you're willing to do right now.  In the meantime, you alternatively could use [`package:basics`](https://pub.dev/packages/basics) and use `snapshot.data.get('totalDaily')?.get('ENERC_KCAL')?.get('quantity') == null`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, to avoid most bugs and data handling issues, I recommend to use an object to represent your food information. You can use [this tool](https://app.quicktype.io/), select Dart as your language, then paste the JSON data in. You now have these objects:

```dart
class Food {
  Food({
    this.totalDaily,
  });

  TotalDaily totalDaily;

  factory Food.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) => Food(
    totalDaily: TotalDaily.fromJson(json["totalDaily"]),
  );

  // I omit the toJson() method since it's not used in this question
}

class TotalDaily {
  TotalDaily({
    this.enercKcal,
    this.fat,
    this.procnt,
    this.chole,
  });

  NutritionValue enercKcal;
  NutritionValue fat;
  NutritionValue procnt;
  NutritionValue chole;

  factory TotalDaily.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) => TotalDaily(
    enercKcal: NutritionValue.fromJson(json["ENERC_KCAL"]),
    fat: NutritionValue.fromJson(json["FAT"]),
    procnt: NutritionValue.fromJson(json["PROCNT"]),
    chole: NutritionValue.fromJson(json["CHOLE"]),
  );
}

class NutritionValue {
  NutritionValue({
    this.quantity,
  });

  int quantity;

  factory NutritionValue.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) => NutritionValue(
    quantity: json["quantity"],
  );
}
```

Then all you need to do is:

```dart
Food food = Food.fromJson(snapshot.data)
```

> Tried calling:

For this issue, it seems like the error can possibly comes from all the engery, fat, protein or cholesterol parsing that use the `quantity` property. In this case, you can do asimple check like this:

```dart
// Example for FAT checking
fat = food.totalDaily.fat?.quantity ?? 0.0
```

Comment: I didn't know there was an automated way to do this, succinct. Thanks a lot.